# How to enable third monitor in Macbook Pro 15'' mid 2015 model?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt, hdmi, displayport

I have Macbook Pro 15'' and have 3 external displays that I want to connect to it. However when I do connect to it using these ports:

1. HDMI
2. HDMI to thunderbolt adapter
3. DVI to Thunderbolt adapter

All three monitors have a maximum resolution of 1920x1080.

I am not able to see one of the monitors. It is no specific monitor. It is the one I end up connecting last. If I restart into Windows I am able to use three monitors. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Allan is correct with his answer in terms of what Apple *officially* supports. However, I am aware of users who have used more displays. Can you clarify whether you're wanting to use these displays while your MBP is in Clam Shell mode? I've seen users connect three external displays while in clamshell mode, but this did result in the MBP's fans spinning at more than double their usual speed when watching videos etc. Not something I would recommend.

Comment: Yes. I plan on using it with the lid closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple doesn't support this configuration.    Per the Apple specifications, you can support up to ***two*** external monitors:

> Dual display and video mirroring: Simultaneously supports full native
>   resolution on the built-in display and up to 3840 by 2160 pixels **on up
>   to two external displays**, both at millions of colors

<sup>(Emphasis added)</sup>